# copying local file after compile time with file resource in CHEF

Tags: file, resources, chef-infra

Trying to copy a file locally that doesn't exist at compile time.
For example:

```
remote_file "/httpfile" do
   source "http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home"
   mode "0666"
end
file "/httpfile.bak" do
   content IO.read("/httpfile")
   only_if {File.exists?("/httpfile")}
end
```

this code will give a `ERROR: No such file or directory -` eventough that the  `only_if` is being used. This is because the `IO.read` happens at compilation time before the file makes it to the system. (4 year old email - http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2011-08/msg00182.html)

Is there a way to force content `IO.read("/httpfile")` to be executed at execution time? or a better way to do this now?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use lazy evaluation to take care of this.  I believe the syntax is this:

```
remote_file "/httpfile" do
   source "https://docs.chef.io/"
   mode "0666"
end
file "/httpfile.bak" do
   lazy { content IO.read("/httpfile") }
   only_if {File.exists?("/httpfile")}
end
```

Comment: The answer is good, I would have preferred using notification from `remote_file` instead of a `only_if` guard to avoid recopying the file at each run. I fail to see the use case with this example (sounds like the backup chef does when replacing a file)